# How to send keys in a input box (Python Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

I tried the following code:

```
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//*[@id='mG61Hd']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[15]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/input").click()
    inputElement.sendKeys('Hello')
```

And I got an error saying:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendKeys'

I even tried putting 'send_keys' instead of 'sendKeys' but the same error.
I think there's a problem with xpath, when I inspect the input box, it doesn't show it's **id**.

Comment: Can you explain me clearly?

Comment: Or directly send me the code please

Comment: remove the `.click()` method and use `sendkeys()` there

Comment: It gives another new error : Attribute Error: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'sendkeys'

Comment: the proper sendkeys method example in python is like this `driver.find_element_by_class_name("contact-data").send_keys()` notice the `_` in function name

Comment: remove this line `inputElement.sendKeys('Hello')` also `send_keys()` will not return anything